# NSMutableArray remove element at row and rearrange all the rows after that

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

As the question states, say I have an NSMutableArray containing 4 rows. I then delete row at position 2 by doing [array removeObjectAtIndex: 2] and I want all subsequent rows to be repositioned so that there is no empty slot in the NSMutableArray. (row 3 to become row 2, and row 4 to become row 3)

Is there a way to quickly do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens automatically when you call removeObjectAtIndex. From the [class reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> To fill the gap, all elements beyond
>   index are moved by subtracting 1 from
>   their index.

Answer (score 1):

It's the behavior of the NSMutableArray !